# How to rename column names on select query of postgres from python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to fetch data from postgres server in python and while on the database the columns are well names such as 'id', 'name', 'email' etc. but when I pull those columns in python, I get column names as 0, 1, 2 etc.

This is my python code:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

DB_HOST = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
DB_NAME = "my_db"
DB_USER = "my_user"
DB_PASS = "********"
PORT = 5432

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=DB_HOST, port = PORT, database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)

# Create a cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT id, name, email FROM users""")

users = cur.fetchall()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

If I check `users`, I get a list as follows:

```
[(13, 'Vaibhav Saxena', 'vaibhavsxn@gmail.com')]
```

Now, I convert this to a pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(users)
```

I get the dataframe as follows:

```
0          1              2
13   Vaibhav Saxena   vaibhavsxn@gmail.com
```

I want the columns 0, 1 and 2 as 'id', 'name' and 'email' just like it is in the database while I select the data and before I convert it to a dataframe. Any hint?

Comment: pass `columns=['id','name','email']`  in `pd.DataFrame()` method....`pd.DataFrame(users,columns=['id','name','email'])`

Comment: I wish to get the names while selecting because in my case, any arbitrary number of columns can be chosen at any time and may not be the same all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
columns = [d[0] for d in cur.description]
pd.DataFrame(users, columns=columns)
```